# Is a recession cone always convex?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

Let $C$ be a set that is not necessarily convex. The recession cone of $C$ is defined as
$$\{y\in C \,\vert\, x + ty \in C, \forall x\in C \text{ and } t\ge 0\}.$$
It seems to me that the recession cone is always convex, even if $C$ is not. Here's why I think that:

Let $y_1,y_2$ be in the recession cone, and $\lambda \in [0,1]$. We want to show that $\lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda)y_2$ is also in the recession cone. Let $x\in C$ and $t\ge 0$, then
$$x + t(\lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda)y_2) = x + t\lambda y_1 + t(1-\lambda)y_2.$$

Since $y_1$ is in the recession cone, we have $x + t\lambda y_1\in C$. And since $y_2$ is also in the recession cone, we must have
$$x + t\lambda y_1 + t(1-\lambda)y_2 \in C.$$

I have seen references, such as Wikipedia, that suggest that $C$ needs to to be convex in order for the recession cone to be convex. That does not seem to be the case, so I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Looking at the Wikipedia article that you mentioned, they claim that convexity of $C$ is need to show that the recession cone is a *convex cone*, or a set where $\alpha x + \beta y \in \textrm{recc}(C)$ for all scalars $\alpha, \beta$. This is a stronger condition than just convexity, which would require $\alpha \in [0, 1]$ and $\beta = 1-\alpha$. Could this be the issue? I don't see any errors in your proof.

Comment: In the section properties on the page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recession_cone, it is mentioned that $C$ (which they call $A$) just has to be a nonempty convex set.  The recession cone is also always a cone. Perhaps the recession cone of a nonconvex set is just rarely useful in practice and is often trivial.